# Selecting specific columns with conditions using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In my Dataframe, I would like to choose only specific columns based on a certain condition from a particular column.

[Here is my output of initial Data Frame using df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb7aR.jpg)

I would like to find for column equals to 'B' and display it with selected columns.

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cancer_data.csv')

#To display column diagnosis equals B
df[df['diagnosis'] == 'B']

#To display selected columns
df[['diagnosis','radius_mean','perimeter_mean','area_mean']]
```

How to merge the condition and display it with selected columns only.

Thanks

Comment: `df[df['diagnosis'] == 'B'][['diagnosis','radius_mean','perimeter_mean','area_mean']]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['diagnosis'] == 'B', ['diagnosis','radius_mean','perimeter_mean','area_mean']]
```